# How to use elimination to solve a system of equations with 3 variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I asked this question before but with a linear algebra angle, however, I need to solve it using the elimination method.

I have been able to solve for $y$, which is $y=\frac{-y''}{2}+\frac{3y'}{2}$, however, I'm not going about solving this in any logical way.  I'm all over the place and feel like I found $y$ by pure luck.

I'm randomly taking derivatives and substiting results into random equations and feel like there is no method to my madness.

How does one approach a problem like this in a logical way?

> $x'=x+2y-z$
>
> $y'=x+z$
>
> $z'=4x-4y+5z$

I need to find $x(t)$, $y(t)$, and $z(t)$

Comment: @Moo but I can't seem to isolate the other variables with any form of fancy substitution.  :(

Comment: @Moo I'm sorry I still don't see it.  My solutions should be in terms of one variable, right?  Yes I solved for $y$, is my solution correct?

Comment: @Moo would you mind just showing me what $y$ should look like?

Comment: @Moo I'm taking an online class and the reading gave one example of the elimination method and all they did was take the derivative and start substituting.  How did you get $y=c_1e^x+c_2e^{2x}$?  Sorry if this seems elementary.

Comment: @Moo I do recognize that as a general solution, but not exactly sure where it came from given the system of equations.

Comment: @Moo ahh ok, I see what you mean now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure where you could have made your mistake, but the solution given above for $y$ is wrong. Start with
$$\begin{align}x^{\prime} & =x+2y-z\\
y^{\prime} & =x+z\\
z^{\prime} & =4x-4y+5z\end{align}$$
Solve the simplest equation available for one of the variables
$$\begin{align}x & =y^{\prime}-z
\end{align}$$
Then substitute into the other equations
$$\begin{align}y^{\prime\prime}-z^{\prime} & =y^{\prime}-z+2y-z\\
z^{\prime} & =4y^{\prime}-4z-4y+5z\end{align}$$
Simplify
$$\begin{align}y^{\prime\prime}-y^{\prime}-2y & =z^{\prime}-2z\\
4y^{\prime}-4y & =z^{\prime}-z\end{align}$$
Subtract the second equation from the first
$$\begin{align}y^{\prime\prime}-5y^{\prime}+2y & =-z\\
\end{align}$$
We can differentiate and substitute into one of the equations
$$\begin{align}4y^{\prime}-4y & =-y^{\prime\prime\prime}+5y^{\prime\prime}-2y^{\prime}+y^{\prime\prime}-5y^{\prime}+2y\\
\end{align}$$
Simplify our differential equation for $y$
$$\begin{align}y^{\prime\prime\prime}-6y^{\prime\prime}+11y^{\prime}-6y & =0\\
\end{align}$$
If we try the solution $y=e^{rt}$ we find
$$r^3-6r^2+11r-6=(r-1)(r-2)(r-3)=0$$
So the general solution for $y$ is
$$y=c_1e^t+c_2e^{2t}+c_3e^{3t}$$
We had an equation a while back the gave $z$ in terms of $y$ so now
$$z=c_1(-1+5-2)e^t+c_2(-4+10-2)e^{2t}+c_3(-9+15-2)e^{3t}=2c_1e^t+4c_2e^{2t}+4c_3e^{3t}$$
And now go back to that equation where so long ago we had solved for $x$ in terms of $y$ and $z$
$$x=c_1(1-2)e^t+c_2(2-4)e^{2t}+c_3(3-4)e^{3t}=-c_1e^t-2c_2e^{2t}-c_3e^{3t}$$
Check by differentiating and substituting into the original differentialequation, and you're done.